# "Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled" error when attempting to change screen

Tags: libgdx

I have a blue square, and when the blue square is moved to the finish flag, the screen should change to signify that the level is complete. However, when I move the blue square to such position, I get an error message:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLChecks.ensureArrayVBOenabled(GLChecks.java:77)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(GL20.java:892)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGL20.glVertexAttribPointer(LwjglGL20.java:847)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.setVertexAttribute(ShaderProgram.java:662)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.VertexBufferObject.bind(VertexBufferObject.java:202)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.bind(Mesh.java:380)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.bind(Mesh.java:371)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.render(Mesh.java:479)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.render(Mesh.java:422)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.flush(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:151)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.end(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:160)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.end(ShapeRenderer.java:1104)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.check(ShapeRenderer.java:1087)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.polygon(ShapeRenderer.java:1014)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.polygon(ShapeRenderer.java:1043)
at com.ian.redsquare.Entities.Walls.render(Walls.java:22)
at com.ian.redsquare.Screens.RedSquareScreen.render(RedSquareScreen.java:65)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

here is the screen class in which the blue square moves:

```
package com.ian.redsquare.Screens;

import ...

public class RedSquareScreen implements Screen{

RedSquareGame game;

Viewport gameViewport;
ShapeRenderer renderer;

RedSquare redSquare;
BlueSquare blueSquare;
FinishSquare finishSquare;
Walls walls;

public RedSquareScreen(RedSquareGame game){
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
public void show() {
    gameViewport = new ExtendViewport(C.WORLD_SIZE, C.WORLD_SIZE, C.WORLD_SIZE, C.WORLD_SIZE);
    renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setAutoShapeType(true);

    finishSquare = new FinishSquare(blueSquare);
    redSquare = new RedSquare();
    blueSquare = new BlueSquare(redSquare);
    walls = new Walls();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    redSquare.update(delta);
    blueSquare.update(delta);

    if(finishSquare.position.dst(blueSquare.position) <= 0){
        game.showLevelEndScreen();

    }

    gameViewport.apply(true);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(C.BACKGROUND_COLOR.r, C.BACKGROUND_COLOR.g, C.BACKGROUND_COLOR.b, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(gameViewport.getCamera().combined);
    renderer.begin();

    finishSquare.render(renderer);
    redSquare.render(renderer);
    blueSquare.render(renderer);
    walls.render(renderer);

    renderer.end();


}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gameViewport.update(width, height, true);

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    renderer.dispose();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

here is screen class which is meant to appear once the blue square reaches the finish square:

```
package com.ian.redsquare.Screens;

import ...

public class LevelEndScreen extends InputAdapter implements Screen {

RedSquareGame game;
Viewport viewport;
ShapeRenderer renderer;
SpriteBatch batch;

public LevelEndScreen(RedSquareGame game){
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
public void show() {
    viewport = new ExtendViewport(C.LE_WORLD_SIZE, C.LE_WORLD_SIZE);
    renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setAutoShapeType(true);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);


}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    viewport.apply();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(C.LE_BACKGROUND_COLOR.r, C.LE_BACKGROUND_COLOR.g, C.LE_BACKGROUND_COLOR.b, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);
    renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    renderer.setColor(C.RESTART_COLOR);
    renderer.rect(C.LE_WORLD_SIZE / 4, C.LE_WORLD_SIZE / 2, C.BUTTON_SIZE, C.BUTTON_SIZE);
    renderer.setColor(C.NEXT_LEVEL_COLOR);
    renderer.rect((C.LE_WORLD_SIZE * (3 / 4)) - C.BUTTON_SIZE, C.LE_WORLD_SIZE / 2, C.BUTTON_SIZE, C.BUTTON_SIZE);

    renderer.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height, true);

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    batch.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}

@Override
public boolean touchDown (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    Vector2 worldTouch = viewport.unproject(new Vector2(screenX, screenY));
    if(worldTouch.dst2(new Vector2(C.LE_WORLD_SIZE / 4, C.LE_WORLD_SIZE / 2)) == 0){
        game.showRedSquareScreen();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Might try moving your game.showLevelEndScreen() call out of the render method. Think rendering runs on its own thread and changing screens inside a render method (especially if you have screen dispose methods elsewhere in your code) could lead to unexpected behaviour (like you're getting now). Or don't have your render method change screens, but then still have render calls after the screen change (render walls, etc ...)

Comment: I put the block of code at the end of the render method and it worked, thanks!